# Itunes music folders

Tags: music, itunes

I have managed to get into the Itunes_Control folder and find all the music files but what I want to do now is put music into it so my Ipod will recognise the new music files and will be able to play them but I have no idea what all the random words or numbers mean, is anyone able to help?

Comment: iPod devices can only be (fully) accessed/edited through software and also the random numbers and word are a sort of encryption, to prevent exactly that, what you are trying to archive manually! I haven't found any good/efficient solutions to your/my problem yet, so I use both OS X for iTunes music and iPod management and Ubuntu (mostly) for my other work.

Comment: I run Windows 7 / itunes for the iphone in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want your music player to act like a flash drive, in that you can just drag and drop files. This is not possible with an iPod. If you want to be able to do this I recommend a different portable music player such as from Sansa. If you want to stick with an iPod, you have to use a program that supports them to edit your music library.